# changing mysql primary key values and corresponding foreign keys

Tags: mysql, database, primary-key, auto-increment

Currently, I am creating a set of records and auto-incrementing the id. I am thinking of using id as a hash of unique fields to speed things up, but its possible that new fields will be added and recomputing ids will be necessary. Is there any way to reassign new ids and automatically change its corresponding foreign key ids? Or does this have to be done manually?

Comment: If you use the InnoDB storage engine, a foreign key constraint "ON UPDATE CASCADE" will do that for you

Comment: Why do you think a hash would be any faster than using an AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY as foreign key reference?